# menu using category and tags

Tags: categories, tags, urls

I'd like to do (somehow) manual menus that would display all posts within certain category.

Eg, I'd have sections "applications" and "games" so now i can do this:
www.site.com/category/applications,games/ and get all from both categories

I can do 
www.site/com/tags/android,iphone,ipad/  - which would give me all related, but from both categories.

I'd like to keep categories and do something like
www.site.com/category/applications&tags/android,iphone,ipad/

That would only display applications avoiding games.

Is that possible without additional plugins and such stuff ?

Tnx.